# grid of 30 images to fade in/out acording to category clicked - jquery fade

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a grid of around 30 cells each with two images, a plain and an active.

Next I have a list of categories, which are assigned to the cells according to their content (wordpress generates these).

Once a category is clicked I need all of the cells which are relevant to that category to fade in or remain active and all of the cells which aren't in that category to fade out.

I have wordpress adding relevant classes to the tiles for categories.

I have a working version of this but it's really slow and I've written much more code than seems appropriate.

Can anyone set me in the right direction?

Comment: It would be useful to see a working example of the code you have. Trying to recommend optimisations or new directions without knowing the current codebase is not really possible. You could use http://jsfiddle.net/ to post an example and provide us a link if you don't want to link to your development/live site.

Comment: Point us at your site. It's MUCH easier to troubleshoot/help when we know the specifics.  For example: Does the list of categories have css classes or id's? Do the table cells have classes, or the images, or...?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I really think i need to start from scratch, I was using the jcycle plugin for some reason. I can add classes or id's to either the cells or the images. The same with the list of categories.

Really I suppose I'm asking what the most sensible approach would be to writing this, theoretically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo that is similar to what you are asking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/AST9r/1/

This fades in/out various squares depending on the color clicked.

Comment: Ha! That is excellent, you would not believe how much code I wrote to get that working badly. I really need to spend some time learning javascript, it seems you can't just wing it.

Thanks Jeff